# How can I create a trigger for table logs using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you help me with my code? Because I am creating a table logs for my project. So I include a TRIGGER in my table but there's an error with my sql code. Here's my sql codes.

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_category` (
    `salescatid` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `salescatname` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `salescatdesc` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `salescatname` (`salescatname`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `salescatid` (`salescatid`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `category_log` (
    `action` ENUM('CREATE','UPDATE','DELETE') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `salescatname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `salescatdesc` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


//Here's the error: SQL error 1054: Unknown column 'id' in 'NEW'
DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER ai_category
AFTER INSERT ON sales_category
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO category_log(action,id,salescatname,salescatedesc)
    VALUES('CREATE',NEW.id,NEW.salescatname,NEW.salescatdesc);
END;#
```

Please help me with this thanks. I can't spot where did I go wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found my error. I just rename the fields in category_log exactly the sa me as my sales_category table.